# $.getJSON unable to call Codebehind [WebMethod] asp,net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, getjson

I am a newbie in jquery. Actually I am not able to call a WebMethod which is in ProcesAPI.aspx page.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string GetJsonData()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var persons = new List<Person>
                              {
                                  new Person{Id = 1, FirstName = "F1", 
                                      LastName = "L1", 
                                      Addresses = new List<Address>
                                                      {
                                                          new Address{Line1 = "LaneA"},
                                                          new Address{Line1 = "LaneB"}
                                                      }},

                                  new Person{Id = 2, FirstName = "F2", 
                                      LastName = "L2", 
                                      Addresses = new List<Address>
                                                      {
                                                          new Address{Line1 = "LaneC"},
                                                          new Address{Line1 = "LaneD"}
                                                      }}};

        string result = js.Serialize(persons);
        return result;
    }
```

The Page from which i am generating the page is "MyForm.aspx" and this is my page frpm which i am calling my processApi GetJsonData method.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
                $.getJSON('ProcessAPI.aspx\GetJsonData', null, function (data) {
                    var div = $('#ajaxDiv');
                    div.html("<br/> " + "Persons received from server: " + "<br/>");
                });
                alert('Hii I ');
                return false;
            });
        });

        function printPerson(div, item) {
            div.append("<br/>" + "FName: " + item.FirstName + ", LName: " + item.LastName);
            $.each(item.Addresses, function (i, addr) {
                printAddress(div, addr);
            });
        }

        function printAddress(div, item) {
            div.append("<br/>" + "   " + "Line1: " + item.Line1);
        }
```

but my method is not getting called... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the method static

```
public static string GetJsonData()
```

Answer (score -1):

try [WebMethod] only with no session